# C Fread Split Textfile into Chunks

Tags: c, string, pointers, void, fread

i've got a Textfile of Unknown Size and have to send it via Sockets from my Server to the Client in Chunks of a certain (variable Size).

How can i use Fread for that Task? I read alot about Fread but im Struggeling with the kind of Pointer i should pass that function in my Case?

size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );

Comment: Write some code, debug it, and show it to us. Try.

Comment: The function prototype tells you what kind of pointer you can use; anything.  It's `void *`.

Comment: Just keep reading it in chunks until you reach the end.  Pick some block size to use.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

> How can i use fread for that task?

Simply keep sending chunks (of fixed size) from the Server to the Client, until there is nothing else to be sent by the Serve.

> What kind of pointer I should pass that function in my case?

Anything.

Check [`fread()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/)'s example, where the `buffer` that is passed in `fread()` is of type `char`, and `fread()` simply allows for it, since the first argument of that function is:

```
size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );
```

So just pass the array you are using to store the data (the chunks) to the function.

Answer (score -1):

To read file as chunks and send them to socket you'll have to decide a size of the chunk.

For example: `4096` is perfect size that's not too big or not too small!

## Example

We choose `4096` bytes as the chunk size. It's btw customizable.

Send the chunk data to the Client when received from file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(ssize_t argc, char** argv)
{
    // We're going to use "rb" because in (WINDOWS) you need it!
    FILE*   fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    char    byte_buffer[4096];
    size_t  bytes_read = 0;

    while(( bytes_read = fread(&byte_buffer, 4096, 1, fp) )> 0)
        send_data_chunk_to_client_somehow(/* your parameters here */);
}
```

---

> The text file should be read in chunks and send them to the Client.
>
> #### [`fread(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) ― Binary stream I/O
>
> `fread(3)` is compatible with both text and binary streams, it's a part of **ANSI C**. The POSIX [`read(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/read) is a equivalent to the function and faster than it.
>
> ```
> size_t fread(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE* fp);
> ```

Comment: Technically your while-loop is flawed: each iteration reads 1 element of 4096 bytes. `fread` returns the number of elements, not the number of bytes. So `bytes_read` is always 1 or 0 instead of 0...4096. If you swap your parameters 4096 and 1 then your variables are named correctly.